# Card type is not supported - paytabs

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway, payment, paytabs

I am integrating paytabs payment method, everything was going fine. But every time I enter test credit card number it says 'Card type is not supported'. I am putting card numbers from their [mentioned test cards](https://support.paytabs.com/en/support/solutions/articles/60000679262-test-cards-and-3d-secure-testing). screen shot is attached. Does any one know what i'm doing wrong or what card should i try. Thanks[image]

Comment: Are you able to sort-out this issue?

Comment: use `paytabs_pt2` npm package and everything will be okay